# MySQL Error #1064 for WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

So I just updated phpMyAdmin for my MAMP local development as suggested by phpMyAdmin.

I use MAMP right now mostly to develop WordPress sites locally.

Now, every time I want to create a new database, I get this error:

```
SELECT MAX( version ) FROM.WHERE `db_name` =  'temp'
AND  `table_name` =  ''
AND FIND_IN_SET(  'CREATE DATABASE', tracking ) >0
```

> MySQL said:
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL >server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `db_name` = 'temp'  AND `table_name` = >''  AND FIND_IN_SET('CREATE DATABAS' at line 1

However, the database is still created.

Now every time I click on a database, I get this error like this (in this example ,the name of the database is 'ios'

```
SELECT tracking_active FROM.WHERE db_name =  'ios'
AND table_name =  'wp_commentmeta'
ORDER BY version DESC
```

> MySQL said:
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE db_name = 'ios'  AND table_name = 'wp_commentmeta'  ORDER BY version DESC' at line 1

I don't have a lot of knowledge on MySQL to be able to figure this error out. If anyone out there who has the same issue/ knows what's going on, I would really appreciate the help in figuring this out.

Comment: I asked this question, but was voted down for some reason even though I still don't have the answer yet. Could someone explain/ help me with this?

Comment: since this question is closed i can't put the answer but the problem resides in phpmyadmin' confic.inc.php file. If you made any changes there revert them back or change the lines that begin with $cfg with the following: 

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
`

Comment: continued:

`$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';`

Comment: it's stupid they closed it as `too localized`

Answer (score 3):

I noticed at `FROM.WHERE`, there is a `dot`.
It's a typo, or it's in your source code.

#1064 is a syntax error; you should always check your SQL statement first.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where I can check the source code? This is a default WordPress install, so I didn't make any change to any SQL statement.

Comment: Hi - if you mean Wordpress plugin, no I don't think so. If you mean a different kind of plugin, the answer is not that I know of.